# Flutter how to give triangle shape to container?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a simple container with border radius

like this

```
            Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 500,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(30), bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30), bottomRight: Radius.circular(30),),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                          blurRadius: 7,
                          color: Color(0xffecedf1),
                          spreadRadius: 4)
                    ])),
```

Its square type shape i want to give a triangle one side shape like this

[image]

Need to know how can i achieve this type of container ?

Comment: you can use ClipPath widget

Answer (score 3):

you can use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_clippers) package.

after adding that widget write your code like

```html
ClipPath(
            clipper: RoundedDiagonalPathClipper(),
            child: Container(
              height: 320,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50.0)),
                color: Colors.orange,
              ),
              child: Center(child: Text("RoundedDiagonalPathClipper()")),
            ),
          ),
```

it will work.

Solution :- 2

you can make custom shape in [this](https://fluttershapemaker.com/)

reference:- https://blog.logrocket.com/drawing-shapes-in-flutter-with-custompaint-and-shape-maker/